# Why is it that when the same query is executed twice in MySQL, it returns two very different response times?

Tags: mysql

my question is as follows:

Why if I do the same query two times in shell MySql get two very different response times (ie,

the first time and the second a much shorter time)?

and how can I do to prevent this from happening??

thank you very much in advance

Comment: Query caching may be turned on; that would be by design then, nothing to change there

Comment: Do you want both to have the short time or the long time?  It is easy to make the shorter one take longer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is most likely down to query and/or result caching. if you run a query once, MySQL stores the compiled version of that query, and also has the indexes stored in memory for those particular tables, so any subsequent queries are vastly faster than the original.

Comment: set query_cache_size=0 in my.ini and restart mysqld

Answer (score 2):

This could be due to **1.query caching is turned on or due to 2.the difference in performance states of the system in which it is being executed**.
In query caching if you run a query once mysql stores the compiled version of the query and is fetched when called again . the time for compiling is not there in the repeated execution of the same query  . ***query caching can be turned off but it is not a good idea***

Comment: I agree that it is not a good idea.
but I am comparing two different types of database and I want to compare the execution times of the queries.
So .. how can I turned off query caching?

Comment: setting the query cache size to 0 disables it

Comment: mysql> SET GLOBAL query_cache_size = 0; dont forget to check my answer as correct

Comment: if you are testing two different databases to see which is the fastest, do you mean two different engines? if so, you should be aware that almost all engines and platforms have query caching, and disabling it would put this as an unfair and unrepresentative test.